# Creating folder in NPM script with cross platform

Tags: npm

I want to create a folder in a NPM script.

I tried:

`mkdir ~/bla || mkdir %HOMEPATH%\\bla`

In unix ofcourse it works, but I get access denied in Windows.

Anyway, is there a way to write the script without this strange fallback?
I want a script for mkdir without specifying specific os-command.

Answer (score 1):

The usual recommendation is to use a node script, for mkdir you can use an existing [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp).

```
scripts: {
  mk: "npx mkdirp ..."
}
```